# Как из строки достать номер телефона Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

**Есть** строка вида: "<sip:[*тут может быть что угодно, либо ничего*]**79811583800**@192.91.235.4:5060;texttexttext>"

**Нужно** достать первые "11" символов влево от "@" и сделать так, чтобы первый символ был "7"

 
**Подскажите** пожалуйста, какие функции для этого использовать и возможно ли это сделать без костылей и тысячи проверок? ЯП - Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
val input = "<sip:[тут может быть что угодно, либо ничего]79811583800@192.91.235.4:5060;texttexttext>"
val sip = input.split("@")[0].takeLast(11)
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос, в исходном вопросе требуется проверить первый символ.

Comment: @Vadik, здесь пример для первой половины вопроса _Нужно достать первые "11" символов влево от "@"_

Comment: @Vadik, я подкорректировал вопрос, теперь это точный ответ.